# Matrix representation of complex map

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis, vector-spaces

I've been working on representing linear maps as matrices but I'm having trouble representing this particular map

Thanks in advance

> Considering $\mathbb{C}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, find the matrix representing the map
>
> $$T:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}, z\rightarrow(1+2i)\bar{z}$$
> relative to the basis $(1,i)$ of $\mathbb{C}$

Answer (score 0):

Multiplication by $(1+2i)$ would be $\frac{1}{\sqrt3}R_{\pi/4}$ where $R_{\pi/4}$ is rotation by $\frac{\pi}{4}$ radians and complex conjugatation is a reflection across the real axis. If you let $E$ be the matrix of such a reflection, then all you need to do is multiply the two matrices: $E(\frac{1}{\sqrt3}R_{\pi/4})$ to get your result (of course you will need to find those matrices as well).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Start by writing $z=x+iy$.  Your transformation takes 
\begin{align}
z&\to z’=(1+2i)z^*\, ,\\
x+iy&\to x’+iy’=(1+2i)(x-iy)= (x+2y)+i (2x-y)\, , \tag{1}
\end{align}
Find the corresponding matrix transformation from (1) should be simple enough.

Comment: \begin{bmatrix}
    x+2y       & y-2x \\
    2x-y       & x+2y\\
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Have I made any mistakes on this last step?  It's primarily converting a linear transformation into a matrix which I struggle with

Comment: @johnfowles $$
\left(\begin{array}{c}
x’\\y’\end{array}\right)= \left(\begin{array}{cc} m_{11}&m_{12}\\ m_{21}&m_{22}\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} x \\ y\end{array}\right)
$$

Comment: I'm still unsure of what you did.  Could you explain

Comment: @johnfowles express the real part of $z’$ as a linear combo of the real and imaginary parts of the transformed $z$; same for the imaginary part of $z’$.